# Python, how to calculate the difference between lists

Tags: python, list, difference

I have list

`a = [('A', 10, 7), ('B', 30, 5), ('C', 73, 12), ('D', 3, 12)]`

and need to calculate the difference between two neighbor points in this list.

For example, (B-A), (C-B), (D-C) and get this output:

`output = [(20, -2), (43, 7), (-70, 0)`

Are there any fast ways how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The question becomes trivial if you turn neighbors into pairs. This is [the trick](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```py
a = [('A', 10, 7), ('B', 30, 5), ('C', 73, 12), ('D', 3, 12)]

firsts = a[:-1]  # a without the last element.
seconds = a[1:]  # a without the first element.
pairs = zip(firsts, seconds)

for (first, second) in pairs:
  # Here first would be e.g. ('A', 10, 7),
  # and second would be e.g. ('B', 30, 5)
  # You can handle the rest yourself.
  print('first:', first, 'second:', second)  # To understand how it works.
  pass
```

Comment: Well, this won't work this way, because `list(pairs)` exhausts the `zip` object, and your `for` loop will iterate on an empty object. Either remove the `print`, or recreate the `zip`, or turn it into a list and `print` and loop on the list. But using `zip` would be the cleanest approach anyway;

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
a = [('A', 10, 7), ('B', 30, 5), ('C', 73, 12), ('D', 3, 12)]

result = [ (second - a[i+1][1], third - a[i+1][2] )   for i, (first, second, third) in enumerate(a[:-1]) ]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,x in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    output.append((a[i+1][1]-a[i][1],a[i+1][2]-a[i][2]))
```

Comment: While your post may answer the question - please add some explanation as to how it does.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using *list comprehension* could be:

```
a = [('A', 10, 7), ('B', 30, 5), ('C', 73, 12), ('D', 3, 12)]
output = [ (a[i+1][1] - a[i][1], a[i+1][2] - a[i][2]) for i in range(len(a)-1) ]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to assume anything about the length

```
i=0
index=0
while i<len(a)-1:
    for ValueA in a[i]:
        if str(ValueA).isdigit():
            print(str(a[i+1][index])+" "+str(ValueA))
        index+=1
    i+=1
    index=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import sub
a = [('A', 10, 7), ('B', 30, 5), ('C', 73, 12), ('D', 3, 12)]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    print(tuple(map(sub, a[i+1][1:],a[i][1:])))
```

Try this. Also show us what you have tried.